# Symfony 4 Twig Set background image without attachement

Tags: templates, twig, background-image, symfony4

I'm trying to set a background image in my template email, but without attachement.
I've tried to upload the image in the server, it works fine but to view the email it needs to click for downloading it.

I've tried this :

```
<div style="background-image: url({{asset('logo.jpg')}})">
```

and this :

```
<div style="background-image: url('{{ email.image('@img/logo.jpg') }}')">
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you need an absolute URL (starting with http://your.domain.com/etc) for the image to work inside the email:

```
<div style="background-image: url({{ absolute_url(asset('logo.jpg')) }})">
```